# Two gridview's selected indexchanged event does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I set two Gridview in one page. one's selected index changed event's load another event. But 2nd grid's selectedindexchanged event goes on first's selectedindexchanged event. What can I do? My function name was correct. Not conflicting any other.

Here my asp code :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdv" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="gdv_RowDataBound" 
                onselectedindexchanged="gdv_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True" 
                Width="100%" onpageindexchanging="gdv_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Sl" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        HeaderText="SL #" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesOrderNo" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Order No" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Section Id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Section Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OutletID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Outlet Id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OutletName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="outlet Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesPersonID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Sales Person Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderDate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Order Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderValue" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Order Value" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkOrderList" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValCheckOrder" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="btnView" Text="View" runat="server" CommandName="ViewIndividualOrder" />--%>
                     <asp:Button ID="btnViewOrder" runat="server" Text="View" ValidationGroup="ValCheckOrder"
                        CommandName="ViewIndividualOrder" OnClick="btnViewOrder_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:GridView>

<asp:GridView ID="gdvOrderDetail" runat="server" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" onrowdatabound="gdvOrderDetail_RowDataBound" 
                onselectedindexchanged="gdvOrderDetail_SelectedIndexChanged" AllowPaging="True" 
                Width="100%" onpageindexchanging="gdvOrderDetail_PageIndexChanging">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Sl" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        HeaderText="SL #" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Product ID" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Product Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Unit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="PacketSize" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Packet Size" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sales Rate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblSalesRate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SalesRate") %>' Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                   <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="SalesRate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Sales Rate" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>--%>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderQty" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Order Qty" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="MemoQty" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMemoQty" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Width="100px" OnTextChanged="txtMemoQty_TextChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="true" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers();"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorMemoQTY" ValidationGroup="ValCheckOrderDetail"
                        runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMemoQty" ErrorMessage="*" Font-Size="X-Large"
                        ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Amount") %>' Font-Size="Smaller" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
                    <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
                        HeaderText="Amount" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </asp:BoundField>--%>
                   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkOrderList" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValCheckOrderDetail" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                </Columns>
                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

C# code:

```
protected void gdv_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int indx = 0;
    indx = gdv.SelectedIndex;

    string salesorderno = "";
    string sectionid = "";
    string sectionname = "";
    string outletid = "";
    string outletname = "";
    string salespersonname = "";
    string orderdate = "";
    string ordervalue = "";
    string ordercheck = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        salesorderno = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        sectionid = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        sectionname = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[3].Text.ToString();
        outletid = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[4].Text.ToString();
        outletname = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[5].Text.ToString();
        salespersonname = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[6].Text.ToString();
        orderdate = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[7].Text.ToString();
        ordervalue = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[8].Text.ToString();
        ordercheck = gdv.Rows[indx].Cells[9].Text.ToString();
    }

    lblOrderNo.Text = salesorderno;
    lblSectionName.Text = sectionname;
    lblOutletName.Text = outletname;
    lblOrderDate.Text = orderdate;

    LoadOrderReportDetailGrid(salesorderno);
}

protected void gdvOrderDetail_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: what do you mean by this -I set two Gridview in one page. one's selected index changed event's load another event. ? I can see only one grid in code?

Answer (score 0):

test is sufficient to know the origin of the event.
Exemple :

```
        private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(dataGrid1.SelectedItem!=null)
                MessageBox.Show("aaaaaaaaaaa");
        }

        private void dataGrid2_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGrid2.SelectedItem != null)
                MessageBox.Show("BBBBBbbBBBB    ");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the event window for the gridviews then select one of them and on the event window double click on the "selected index changed" event. it will move you to the code section. if you are in true procedure than the event binding is true. if not you have to change the definition of your procedure.

Here is the simple process.

1. copy the codes inside the procedure and paste them to a safe place.
2. delete the procedures related the gridviews
3. check the event page for gridviews to ensure there is nothing in the "selected index changed" event.
4. double click the first gridviews "selected index changed" event. it will create a blank procedure. paste the related code here.
5. do the same for second.

and the other thing check the validation groups of the gridviews in the properties window. they should be different :)

NOT: forgive me that i cannot write the code directly. because i am not with my own computer. I hope it works.

Comment: thank you. i solve that problem by take a new grid. and the problem was with the validation name.